# Angular - Dynamically create input[text] fields

Tags: angularjs

When creating input[text] fields, you assign an ng-model object to it. That ngModel is hardcoded in the scope like `$scope.userName` or `$scope.lastname`.

My problem is that i have a click event that adds input fields on demand. That means that i can't hardcode those object.

What I did is make them array blocks, with scope object...

```
$scope.example = {
    counter: 0,
    data: []
}
```

`counter` property would be incremented every type the input field is created on a user click event. So, `ng-model` property would be like this...

```
ng-model="example.data[example.counter]"
```

If the user creates 3 input fields, there would be 3 array values.

The problem is that those array values are not updated on model changes. Only the first input field is populated in the `example.data` array but on the third (2) index.

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there an angular way of dynamiclly creating input fields. This was my first raw try but I have a couple of ideas that involve broadcasting an event which are much more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use ng-repeat, like:

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="myinput in myinputs" ng-model="myinput">
</input>
```

And when u need new input - just add new value to myinputs array.

Answer (score 1):

Petr Averyanov answer was great and simple but it still didn't bind the model to the input values.

I managed to do that like this...

```
 <input type="text"
        ng-repeat="data in innerBlock.data track by $index"
        ng-model='innerBlock.data[$index]'>
```

`track by $index` is neccessary if you put the same value in every index of the array.

And the guts of the directive...

```
scope.example.counter++;
scope.example.data[scope.example.data.length] = '';
```

I was brainstorming a really complicated way but this is just too simple its great.